# What is the effect of timer control on IIS when used in .net web service

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I want to know that What is the effect of timer control on IIS when used in .net web service. i.e. how much increase in the resource consumption of W3WP process.

Comment: Why don't you simply give it a try?

Comment: Which timer control are you referring to?  If you mean Microsofts Ajax timer control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865.aspx), server resource consumption will depend on how often the timer fires, and how long it takes the postback to complete each time it fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use timers in a Web service. Since HTTP is stateless, you're serving resources and closing the whole connection with the client in a few milliseconds. That is, you don't want long processes since you want to prioritize more concurrent requests than long requests.

If you need to perform background processing, you should use a Windows service.

Take a look at [Topshelf documentation](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get started with Windows service development.

Comment: Hi Matias, can you please tell me what are the benefits of using Topshelf.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey This is off-topic to your question... It's just makes Windows service development easier.